Qt/QML - Getting *qml* stack trace from Non UI thread is always crashing
In a certain QML app there is a problem that sometimes QML scripts hang UI thread for very long times, like 20+ seconds of UI thread not processing any incoming events from any source. In rare cases it can just hang forever like this.
To track such cases, we added a background thread that pings the main thread with events and measures what is the last time its event was processed. That gives us a good way to find out when UI was completely "hanged" - that is UI is non responsive, clicking on app shows "App is hanged: Kill/Wait for app to respond".
If hanging part is on our native code, we just use thread stack trace and get where it happened. However, if hanging happened in QML part, we need to get qml stack trace, and since main(UI) thread is frozen, we can't get it from there.
So what we tried, is first calling qmlEngine.evaluate("console.trace()") from our bg thread and it got us crashes happening almost every time.
"Ok," we thought, " perhaps evaluating js code makes some other events to also process in our non UI thread that aren't allowed there."
So we decided to try calling extern "C" Q_QML_EXPORT char *qt_v4StackTraceForEngine(void *executionEngine) from our non-UI thread.
I've checked its implementation, and it doesn't seem to do any event processing or garbage collecting, just a simple "get current stack trace and send it", yes it still crashes in Qt6Qml.dll almost every time its called.
The question is - why is it crashing? How can we avoid it? Running in UI thread is not an option since this code is running only when UI thread is not available.
We don't seem to interact with any code that would require to be ran in UI thread only, yet crash is still there.
For reference, here is the implementation of function that we've used from qv4engine.cpp:
/// !!! for demo only, do not copy it
StackTrace ExecutionEngine::stackTrace(int frameLimit) const
{
    Scope scope(const_cast<ExecutionEngine *>(this));
    ScopedString name(scope);
    StackTrace stack;

    CppStackFrame *f = currentStackFrame;
    while (f && frameLimit) {
        QV4::StackFrame frame;
        frame.source = f->source();
        frame.function = f->function();
        frame.line = f->lineNumber();
        frame.column = -1;
        stack.append(frame);
        if (f->isJSTypesFrame()) {
            if (static_cast<JSTypesStackFrame *>(f)->isTailCalling()) {
                QV4::StackFrame frame;
                frame.function = QStringLiteral("[elided tail calls]");
                stack.append(frame);
            }
        }
        --frameLimit;
        f = f->parentFrame();
    }

    return stack;
}

One potential reason could be if main thread recovers while we are running this function and so race condition happens - is there any ways to block main thread from processing new events while this function is running that doesn't reduce UI performance significantly?
Our app is using QTJambi, but I believe it's not affecting this situation.
Thanks!

Not really sure if this helps with your basic problem, but it might be a another approach.
We have a custom event message handler registered with:
qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);.
There we get all console messages written in QML. If you create a timer on QML side writing a log message you will get this message posted to the handler.
So you can check in your bg thread if messages are getting received or if the QML timer is stuck.
